# Detect when page has been visited change image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know there are a few issues with :visited and so now I'm looking for an alternative. I'd like to know if it's possible for a user to visit a certain page on my website and once they go back to the homepage, a different image shows up.

**Update:** there are images in the homepage, when you click on one, it changes to a new one, indicating you've visited the page. BUT how do you detect if you are on another page of the site and you visit the link without clicking the image? I still want the event to trigger the change. Is that even possible?

Comment: by different do you mean there is a random image loaded each time? otherwise do you mean there is a specific image for first time visitors and a different specific image for repeat visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Code to put in every page.
if (session_name() == "")
    session_start();    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['visited']))
        $_SESSION['visited'] = array(); //Init.
    $current_page = "current_page"; // Set the page here.       
    if (!$_SESSION['visited'][$current_page])
        $_SESSION['visited'][$current_page] = 1;

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php foreach ($pages as $page) : ?>
<?php if ($_SESSION['visited'][$page]) : ?><p>Image 1</p><?php else : ?><p>Image 2</p><?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Using PHP Sessions it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of image sources

```
  images = [];
  images[1] = "src of pic1";
  images[2] = "src of pic2";
  //you can have more links if you want

  size = images.length;
  rNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*size);

  document.getElementById("img").src = images[rNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a session cookie when the page is visited.

[This](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) is a great jQuery plugin for cookies.

Homepage code

```
$(function(){
  if($.cookie("interior_page_visited")){
    //display new image
  } else {
    //display initial homepage image
  }
});
```

Interior page code

```
$(function(){
  //set cookie, expires when browser is closed
  $.cookie("interior_page_visited", true);
});
```

Comment: This one works as well, but what if they disable javascript? Thank you so much for your help.