# when my website is load to server image should be displayed but on refresh the page it should not display on refresh of page

Tags: jquery, html

When my website is load to server image should be displayed once but on refresh of the page image should not display on the home page or if I navigate to another page and then return back to same page image should not displayed. Here is the code:

```
<div class="text-center modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div>
      <img src="~/images/onLoad.png" alt="MY COUNTRY - MY PRIDE" class="img-responsive" />
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Here in the code I use javascript in that on windows load function image should be displayed and html file

Comment: You just need to use a cookie

Comment: how can you tell @keepon

Comment: If you can write it on Asp.Net, you won't even need jquery.

Comment: i used mvc @readyfreddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's a proper solution but you can use session to check if you came this page before like that on MVC

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    if(Session["Stat"] == null)
    {
        Session["Stat"] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Session["Stat"] = false;
    }

    return View();
}
```

At first visit of page, `Session["Stat"]` is not defined yet so it's `null`. `Session["Stat"]=true` will be mean for it's your first visit on this page. After you defined `Session["Stat"]`, it will be defined as `false` for every next visites. Than in view, check this session to paste or not that your html img block like this:

```
@{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@if ((bool)Session["Stat"] == true)
{
    <img id="Image1" src="~/Content/Surfing2.jpg" />
}
```

Comment: Can you tag as answer if it solved your problem please?

Comment: You still didn't tick this as answer. What did you mean by query string?

Comment: by using query string we can do this

Comment: So do you mean JQuery?

Comment: If you mean JQuery: There is two way that i know to check if you visit a page. One is using Sessions as i did in this solution. Sessions are server side files and JQuery works on client side so only way to reach them by JQuery is define a hiddenfield, set this value by session then check it by JQuery but this is not a proper solution. Other way is cookies, they are client-side files so you can check them directly with JQuery but still you won't need it.Using JQuery is an unnecessary extra work here but if you still need that, i can work on it.

Comment: maybe or by query string suppose we assign some id in index or any thing

Comment: I don't think so. Every new page and postbacks means every values will be reseted so you can't hold an id or value without session or cookies on web forms or i don't know how if there is a way. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695021/detect-when-page-has-been-visited-change-image

check this. They used cookies or sessions on this solution also.

Comment: kindly do it by jquery